# Something get wrong with musicCursor in "react-native-get-music-files"

Tags: react-native

I am calling this function MusicFiles.getAll. It returns Something get wrong with musicCursor. Instead, it should return an array of all the music tracks.

```
 MusicFiles.getAll({})
        .then(tracks => {
          console.log(tracks);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

The expected output is supposed to be something like this.

```
[
  {
    id : 1,
    title : "La danza del fuego",
    author : "Mago de Oz",
    album : "Finisterra",
    genre : "Folk",
    duration : 132132312321, // miliseconds
    cover : "file:///sdcard/0/123.png",
    blur : "file:///sdcard/0/123.png",
    path : "/sdcard/0/la-danza-del-fuego.mp3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this was happening when no music on my device. I was running an emulator. I copied files using drag n' drop. Files were copied but not showing in device file manager. Restarted the device. Got the files.

Comment: yes. It works on android device. The issue was on emulator